# Cannot import name 'StreamListener' from Tweepy

Tags: python, api, import, tweepy

I was trying to run a Listening in Tw, but when I run my **test_listening.py** script, it shows the following error.

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "test_listening.py", line 1,
> in <module>
>     from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener ImportError: cannot import name 'StreamListener' from 'tweepy.streaming'
> (/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py)
```

I upgraded the Tweepy library, but it didn't work.

Comment: It's necessary to change the code with new tweepy version **4.3.0**. But I install an old version **(version 3.8.0)** and it works using my old code.

Answer (score 1):

[Tweepy v4.0.0](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/releases/tag/v4.0.0) merged `StreamListener` into `Stream`.
I recommend updating your code to subclass [`Stream`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.3.0/stream.html) instead.
Alternatively, you can downgrade to v3.10.0.